# Write a mathematical proof using Microsoft Word

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have an algebraic proof that I want to write online. I tried using Word, but it's very tedious to keep inserting equations to get the proper formatting of the equations and expressions. Plus, it's a line by line proof, so I can't just keep inserting equations on each line. What's the easiest way, even if it isn't Word, to write a properly formatted mathematical algebraic proof?

It's a proof by induction, by the way.

Comment: Learn to [TeX](https://www.latex-project.org).

Comment: The curve may be initially steep, but learning LaTeX will pay off 10-fold in no time.

Comment: And for putting it online (as HTML as opposed to PDF) I've had good luck with HEVEA ( http://hevea.inria.fr/ ).

Comment: Even if you're able to write a proof in word, nobody will read it.

Comment: ^ I cannot stop laughing.  It's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely learn to use LaTeX.  There is a bit of a learning curve but you'll find it absolutely invaluable if you're starting to write proofs / mathematics using computers.